# how to Install easy_install Via yum on Linux CentOS Server

Tags: centos5

please tell me how to Install easy_install Via yum on Linux CentOS Server

i tried that in panel command center

```
yum install python-setuptools
```

output....

> - epel: mirrors.tummy.com  * base:
>     mirrors.tummy.com  * updates:
>     centos.mirrors.tds.net  * addons:
>     mirror.fdcservers.net  * extras:
>     mirrors.gigenet.com 0 packages
>     excluded due to repository protections
>     Setting up Install Process Parsing
>     package install arguments Resolving
>     Dependencies
>     --> Running transaction check
>     ---> Package python-setuptools.noarch 0:0.6c9-5 set to be updated
>     --> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/python26 for package:
>     python-setuptools
>     --> Running transaction check
>     ---> Package python26.i386 0:2.6.5-6.el5 set to be updated
>     --> Processing Dependency: libpython2.6.so.1.0 for package:
>     python26
>     --> Processing Dependency: libffi.so.5 for package: python26
>     --> Running transaction check
>     ---> Package python26-libs.i386 0:2.6.5-6.el5 set to be updated
>     ---> Package libffi.i386 0:3.0.5-1.el5 set to be updated
>     --> Finished Dependency Resolution
>
> Dependencies Resolved
>
> ================================================================================  Package                  Arch
>   Version               Repository
>   Size
>   ================================================================================ Installing:  python-setuptools
>   noarch        0.6c9-5
>   chl         357 k Installing for
>   dependencies:  libffi
>   i386          3.0.5-1.el5
>   epel         21 k  python26
>   i386          2.6.5-6.el5
>   epel        6.5 M  python26-libs
>   i386          2.6.5-6.el5
>   epel        667 k
>
> Transaction Summary
>   ================================================================================ Install      4 Package(s)
>   Update       0 Package(s)
>   Remove       0 Package(s)
>
> Total download size: 7.5 M Is this ok
>   [y/N]: Exiting on user Command
>   Complete!

when i run this command

> easy_install html5lib

then i get error

> sh: easy_install: command not found

so please help me to install easy_install command am using centos 5 32bit

Answer (score 7):

The output you show seems to imply that you exited the download and install without actually doing so.  Try `yum install -y python-setuptools` to finish the install, then try the easy_install command.

Answer (score 1):

Disable the "chl" repo and try again. It's in the base repo.

Answer (score 0):

i tried

```
yum install -y python-setuptools
```

but still not installed

```
  Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, protectbase
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.sanctuaryhost.com
 * updates: mirror.fdcservers.net
 * addons: centos.mirrors.tds.net
 * extras: mirror.fdcservers.net
0 packages excluded due to repository protections
Setting up Install Process
Parsing package install arguments
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package python-setuptools.noarch 0:0.6c9-5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/python26 for package: python-setuptools
--> Running transaction check
---> Package python26.i386 0:2.6.2-2 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libpython2.6.so.1.0 for package: python26
--> Processing Dependency: libffi.so.5 for package: python26
--> Running transaction check
---> Package python26.i386 0:2.6.2-2 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libffi.so.5 for package: python26
---> Package python26-libs.i386 0:2.6.2-2 set to be updated
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
python26-2.6.2-2.i386 from chl has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libffi.so.5 is needed by package python26-2.6.2-2.i386 (chl)
Error: Missing Dependency: libffi.so.5 is needed by package python26-2.6.2-2.i386 (chl)
```

Comment: As @Ignacio-Vazquez-Abrams said, disable repo chl with `--disablerepo=chl` and try again.